# How to parametrize a fixture with multiple parameters

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I have a fixture which in I want to use `request.param` multiple times.

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_settings(request):
    with mock.patch("helpers.helpers.get_settings") as mocked_settings:
        mocked_settings.return_value = Settings(
            TOKEN_KEY=request.param,      # <== Here
            TOKEN_PASSWORD=request.param) # <== And here
        yield


@pytest.fixture
def get_user():
    return User(name="Test User")

def generate_new_token(user: User) -> str:

    settings = get_settings()
    private_key = settings.TOKEN_KEY
    token_password = settings.TOKEN_PASSWORD

    if not private_key.strip():
        raise ValueError("Private key must not be empty")
```

How can I do it? If I do something like above (with two `request.param`), and then use it in my test function like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('get_settings, expected', [(FAKE_TOKEN_KEY, '', None), (FAKE_TOKEN_KEY, '1', None)],
                         indirect=["get_settings"])
def test_generate_new_token(get_user, get_settings, expected):
    assert generate_new_token(user=get_user) == expected
```

I get this error:

> in "parametrize" the number of names (2):   ['get_settings',
> 'expected'] must be equal to the number of values (3)

I'm not sure if it's related to the second fixture (`get_user`) I'm passing to the test function or not. But how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

`None` is the expected value and I put the other two in tuple. But in this case I get following error:

> test setup failed
>
> ```
> request = <SubRequest 'get_settings' for <Function test_generate_new_token[get_settings1-None]>>
>
> @pytest.fixture
> def get_settings(request):
>     with mock.patch("helpers.helpers.get_settings") as mocked_settings:
>       > mocked_settings.return_value = Settings(
>             DEBUG=True,
>             TOKEN_KEY=request.param,  # FAKE_TOKEN_KEY,
>             TOKEN_PASSWORD=request.param)
> ```
>
> ../conftest.py:76:
>
> ---

> pydantic/env_settings.py:36: in pydantic.env_settings.BaseSettings.**init**
> ???
>
> ---
>
> ???
>
> E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Settings
> E   TOKEN_KEY
>
> E     str type expected (type=type_error.str)
>
> E   TOKEN_PASSWORD
>
> E     str type expected (type=type_error.str)
>
> pydantic/main.py:406: ValidationError

Comment: No, it's related to the number of values in `parametrize`, the 2 variables (`get_settings`, `expected`) do not match the 3 values (`FAKE_TOKEN_KEY`, `'1'`, `None`).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen That's where I can't figure out the right way to do it. In all the tutorials I watched, there's just one `request.param` in fixture and that works. But in my case I need more than one and I'm looking for a way to do it.

Comment: Ah ok. You can pass a tuple as request param, as you try to do, but I don't see the `expected` parameter value in your decorator. Also, if you pass a tuple, you have to access the values in the tuple via index in `request.param`.

Comment: If `None` is the expected value (just realized that it may be), then you just forgot to put brackets around the tuple, e.g. `[((FAKE_TOKEN_KEY, ''), None), ...]`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I set the tuples as you suggested. But I'm getting a weird error. I updated my question with that error.

Comment: You didn't change the usage of `param` for the tuple as I wrote, you need something like `TOKEN_KEY=request.param[0]` and `TOKEN_PASSWORD=request.param[1]`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thank you! That fixed the problem. Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't around to write an answer, and now you already did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there were two changes I needed to make in my code to fix the problem:

1- I had to pass the parameters in a tuple:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('get_settings, expected', [
((FAKE_TOKEN_KEY, ''), None), 
((FAKE_TOKEN_KEY, '1'), None)
],
                         indirect=["get_settings"])
```

2- I had to pass the param indexes in the fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_settings(request):
    with mock.patch("helpers.helpers.get_settings") as mocked_settings:
        mocked_settings.return_value = Settings(
            TOKEN_KEY=request.param[0],      # <== Here I added index [0]
            TOKEN_PASSWORD=request.param[1]) # <== And here index [1]
        yield
```